# Using Robot Framework to pick an item from select2 with remote data

Tags: robotframework, jquery-select2

I'm trying to programatically choose an item from a select2 drop down that is populated from remote data.

Here are a couple of test cases based on select2's demo page:

```
*** Settings ***
Library         Selenium2Library

*** Variables ***
${URL}       https://select2.github.io/examples.html
${BROWSER}        Chrome


*** Test Cases ***

Test select2 input with click
    Open browser    ${URL}  ${BROWSER}
    Wait Until Page Contains    Loading remote data
    Click Element   xpath=/html/body/div/div/div[1]/section[3]/p[4]/span
    Input Text      xpath=/html/body/span/span/span[1]/input      robotframework
    Wait Until Page Contains    Generic test automation
    Click Element   xpath=//*[@id="select2-aiw0-results"]/li


Test select2 input with select from
    Open browser    ${URL}  ${BROWSER}
    Wait Until Page Contains    Loading remote data
    Click Element   xpath=/html/body/div/div/div[1]/section[3]/p[4]/span
    Input Text      xpath=/html/body/span/span/span[1]/input      robotframework
    Wait Until Page Contains    Generic test automation
    Select From List By Index   xpath=/html/body/span         0
```

The intention is to open the select2 input from the "Loading remote data" section, enter "robotframework" and finally select the robotframework item. It is that latest action that I can't figure out how to do properly. Here is the output I get from Robot Framework:

```
$ robot select2.robot 
==============================================================================
Select2                                                                       
==============================================================================
Test select2 input with click                                         | FAIL |
ValueError: Element locator 'xpath=//*[@id="select2-aiw0-results"]/li' did not match any elements.
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Test select2 input with select from                                   | FAIL |
ValueError: Element locator 'xpath=/html/body/span' did not match any elements.
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Select2                                                               | FAIL |
2 critical tests, 0 passed, 2 failed
2 tests total, 0 passed, 2 failed
==============================================================================
Output:  /home/al/essai/robotframework/output.xml
Log:     /home/al/essai/robotframework/log.html
Report:  /home/al/essai/robotframework/report.html
```

I get the same result with Chrome and Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

[Maybe with Javascript ?](http://rtomac.github.io/robotframework-selenium2library/doc/Selenium2Library.html#Execute%20Javascript)

And just use select2 function.

Comment: I'd rather use a Robot Framework keyword with a CSS selector. Triggering select2 through JavaScript seems a bit too low level for this kind of test. Thanks anyway for mentioning this, I wasn't aware of it and it could come handy in another situation.

Answer (score 0):

The way to go here is to use the `Click Element` keyword. My first test case wasn't working because it was relying on an id (`select2-aiw0-results`) that is dynamically generated by select2 and that is different during each execution.

Here a test case that works against the select2 demo page:

```
*** Settings ***
Library         Selenium2Library

*** Variables ***
${URL}       https://select2.github.io/examples.html
${BROWSER}        Chrome


*** Test Cases ***

Test select2 input with click
    Open browser    ${URL}  ${BROWSER}
    Wait Until Page Contains    Loading remote data
    # Click on the input
    Click Element   xpath=/html/body/div/div/div[1]/section[3]/p[4]/span
    # Enter text to trigger autocompletion
    Input Text      xpath=/html/body/span/span/span[1]/input      robotframework
    Wait Until Page Contains    Generic test automation
    # Select the first suggestion from the autocompletion list
    Click Element   css=.select2-results li:nth-child(1)
    # Check that the input contains text corresponding to the selected item
    Element Text Should Be  css=body > .container section:nth-child(3) .js-example-data-ajax + .select2-container .select2-selection__rendered    robotframework/robotframework
    Close Browser
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
Select2 Input
[Arguments]     ${css}     ${text}
Execute Javascript   $("${css}").val("${text}"); $("${css}").select2().trigger('change');
```